# Node, Express API Gateway

Tags: node.js, express, url-routing

I'm trying to create a simple API gateway type project that takes in incoming routes and redirects them to other external apis. I'm trying to have an incoming route of `/test` go to google.com or any other API with some req.body but I don't think I am doing it right.

```
var app = express();    
app.get('/test', function(req, res){
var options = {
    host: 'www.google.com',
    port: 80,
    path: '/index.html'
};

var req = http.get(options, function(res) {
    console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
}).on('error', function(e) {
    console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

I'm trying the http.get / post but I can't put them inside the app.get function?

Answer (score 2):

Using Express.js proxying can be done fairly easy using [`http-proxy`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy) lib:

```
let app = require('express')();
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

var apiProxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();

app.get("/*", function(req, res){ 
  apiProxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://google.com' });
});
```

Another variant is to use config based approach with [`express-gateway`](https://www.express-gateway.io/getting-started/) library

Install globally `npm i -g express-gateway`
execute `eg gateway create` to create sample project

inside created directory open `config/gateway.config.yml` file and paste the following config:

```
http:
  port: 8080
apiEndpoints:
  api:
    host: localhost
    paths: '/*'
serviceEndpoints:
  google:
    url: 'https://google.com'
policies:
  - proxy
pipelines:
  - name: default
    apiEndpoints:
      - api
    policies:
      - proxy:
          - action:
              serviceEndpoint: google 
              changeOrigin: true
```

Here is getting started guide:
http://www.express-gateway.io/getting-started/

Answer (score 1):

I now this answer comes rather late, but if you are using `Expressjs` in conjunction with `api-gateway`, there is a new module, [aws-serverless-express](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-express) that can be used to port your `Express` app onto `Api-Gateway`. You can find a [tutorial](https://medium.com/@hyprstack/porting-expressjs-apis-onto-aws-api-gateway-12161c8c0635#.oj9449g97) here!

If what you want is to just redirect users, then simply change your code to use `res.redirect('www.google.com');`, as Lucas mentioned in his answer.

```
var app = express();    
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('www.google.com');
};
```

If what you want, first get data from another API and then display that to the user, I would suggest using the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module, which is battle tested and makes your code look cleaner. 
On the other hand, using `nodejs`'s core `http` module does make your code "lighter".

With the request module you would have

```
var app = express(); 
var request = require('request');   
app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    var options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'www.google.com',
    }
    request(options, function(err, response, body) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).end();
        }
        res.send(body); // send whatever you want here
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now you're trying to define the variable `req`, however the problem here is that this variable represents the request that the server (this code) received. Since its already been sent and captured by the server, you can't change it, this is what the client sent to you.

If I understand you correctly, you want this server to act as a sort of central "API proxy", where it receives requests, and responds with data from various other APIs.

So we can't do anything with `req`, but we can respond to the client with `res`. To do this, create an `http.get` request similar to the one you have, capture the data from this, and then in the callback, use `res.send(data);`

Take a look at the Express docs, they're very helpful. As well, if you're simply trying to redirect the client to another page, there's `res.redirect`, which is very useful. http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect

Edit: Here's an example of what I'm talking about
Edit 2: Fixed pseudo code to real code that runs

```
app.get('/test', function(req, rootRes){
  var options = {
    host: 'jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
    port: 80,
    path: '/users'
  };

  http.get(options, function(res) {
    console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);

    var theData = '';
    res.on('data', function(body){
      theData += body;
    });

    res.on('end',function(){
      console.log(theData);
      if(res.statusCode < 399) {
        rootRes.send(200,theData); //send a success code with the data
      }else{
        rootRes.send(res.statusCode); //send the client whatever error the server experienced
      }
    });
  }).on('error', function(e) {
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
  rootRes.send(501); //internal server error
  });
});
```

Note that I wrote this in 2 minutes, so take this as pseudo code that may not run. Also, look up docs on handling status codes and proper practice.

Comment: once you set the data in var `theData` how do u go about using it in an external api call. From what I understand your code just takes my initial request and pulls its data into the variable `theData` with error handling. aka the variable `getData` is never used. Thanks!

Comment: I can see how that can be a bit confusing. We actually don't need to assign http.get to a variable. I've updated the code, and you can now run this to see how it works. You'll notice the two "res.on" methods which are needed for parsing incoming data. If you want to avoid messing with these, take a look at the NodeJS "request" module.